# Разница между WITH и SELECT FROM SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, оптимизация

В чём разница между использованием `SELECT FROM SELECT` и `WITH`?

Например, есть два запроса:

```sql
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT SUM(D) as sum_d, E, SUM(F) as sum_f FROM second_table GROUP BY E) as second
WHERE second.E == 5
```

и

```sql
WITH second AS
(
    SELECT SUM(D) as sum_d, E, SUM(F) as sum_f FROM second_table GROUP BY E
)
SELECT * FROM second WHERE second.E == 5
```

Будет ли какая-то разница в работоспособности этих двух запросов?

Comment: Если верить информации отсюда: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 то некоторые штуки нельзя использовать с with, но я не проверял, а можно ли их использовать с select from select. В остальном же разницы нет.

Comment: я добавляю ;WITH, когда использую процедуры https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/possible-to-use-a-withas-statement-in-a-stored-procedure , как нам объясняли, их работа более оперативная по сравнению с тем же INTO #table

Answer (score 8):

Нет. Ни в скорости работы, ни в результатах запроса никакой разницы не будет. Это один и тот же запрос, с разным синтаксисом

Answer (score 2):

Что вы подразумеваете под работоспособностью? Если синтаксис правильный, то оба запроса вернут вам одинаковую выборку. По сути, в обоих случаях вы оперируете теми же самыми данными, только в первом у вас подзапрос, а во втором - представление (view). Что касается производительности, то нужно смотреть план запроса, скорее всего всё будет 1:1.

`WITH`-представление чаще всего нужно для переиспользования запроса в нескольких местах.

См. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30078783/12473843

Comment: *"в первом у вас подзапрос, а во втором - представление"* - в первом производная таблица, во втором - общее табличное выражение

Answer (score 2):

Все приведенные запросы имеют один и тот же план выполнения. По факту
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще 1 запрос, аналогичный приведенным

```
SELECT SUM(D) as sum_d, E, SUM(F) as sum_f 
FROM second_table 
GROUP BY E
having e=5
```

Еще запрос (по комментарию @teran). Стоимости не меняются.

```
SELECT SUM(D) as sum_d, E, SUM(F) as sum_f 
FROM second_table 
WHERE E = 5
GROUP BY E
```

Стоимости указаны для таблицы размером 1200 строк.

Comment: тогда и не группировать вовсе, раз уже e=5 то достаточно его в where запихать, `select sum(), 5, sum()`

Comment: @teran, не группировать, кстати, нельзя. Семантика изменится. Если нет строк с `E = 5`, то оригинальный запрос вернёт пустой результат. Без группировки - вернёт одну строку c NULL-ами в суммах.